# Is awaiting an async method that does not return a promise explicitly considered as a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Say I have the following function:

```
const someFunc = async(obj) => {
    const { x, y } = obj;
    const result = await devices.update(
        { x: x, y: y },
        { $set: { z: 1 } },
        { upsert: false }
    );
    if (result.nModified !== 1) throw new Error("Some error");
    return result;
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
try {
    await someFunc();
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I can't return `device.update(...)` since I need to perform the test for the number of documents modified inside the function. I also know that `someFunc()` wraps the returned result in a `Promise` object, but was not sure if this code is considered a clean code.

Comment: This is a valid clean code.

Comment: @AleksandrKyharenko you can add an answer and I will accept it if you like

Comment: It's not a bad practice. However, if the try/catch block exists merely to accommodate for the possible exception, you can simplify it by using `.catch()`.

Comment: It's not considered bad practise to force synchronisation on functions that are natively async. However this would block the main thread, so if your device.update is performing an AJAX call of some sorts and the target of your call is "slow", this might cause inconvience for your users.

Comment: @BRO_THOM, you're right, but I need to turn this into a asynchronous operation as I must perform the update before the code can continue

Comment: @omer It might be useful for us to know what the `devices.update` returns. If it's a Promise you can simple chain it with a `then` or you could wrap your function so it uses a callback such as `somFunc(obj, callback) { return devices.update( /.../ ).then(response => callback(response));`

Comment: @BRO_THOM `device.update()` returns a promise, but I need that the code that calls it will block until this promise is resolved (or rejected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks valid. If you skip `await` then it won't wait until it resolves the `Promise` inside. Instead it is considering the return value as a resolved `Promise`. From the documentation for [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

So I made a quick example just to see the difference without and with `await` keyword.

Please consider the following code.

```js
(async () => {
  console.log('async function started');
  const runAsync = async (value) => {
    const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 2000);
    });
    return result;
  };

  const dataWithoutAwait = runAsync('value');
  console.log('data without await', dataWithoutAwait);

  const dataAwait = await runAsync('value');
  console.log('data with await', dataAwait);
})();
```

I hope this clarifies and help your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong in this. Look perfectly valid.